# Localize Windows Service

Tags: vb.net, localization, windows-services, culture, cultureinfo

I want to Set Culture for Windows Service that I developed. Can someone recommend me a good read for or how to go about it.

So far I have I Tried to do the Following `OnStart()`

```
Dim oCultureInfo as CultureInfo = New CultureInfo("tr-TR")

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Culture = oCultureInfo
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.UICulture = oCultureInfo
```

After doing so I still see that My culture is US English.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to your setup which will be in the same solution.
2. Right click on it and select ADD->PROJECT OUTPUT--> a window will appear.
3. Select Project- your localization project then select from below localized resource.
4. Just click ok. you will see one file is added to setup project.
5. Just compile and install it will work fine.